# angular2 execute unit tests from an external class

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

I'm working on my angular2 tests.

I'm currently using ngx-translate for my application translations, and while doing the translates tests, I was wondering if it was possible to execute tests for a component from an external helper class.

Right now, I'm using the HttpLoader from `ngx-translate`, and I can execute my first tests without any issue :

**randomComponent.spec.ts**

```
  it('should translate in english', async(() => {
    // Get the service
    translateService = TestBed.get(TranslateService);
    expect(translateService).toBeTruthy();
    checkTranslations(fixture, 'en', translateService);
  }));

  it('should translate in french', async(() => {
    // Get the service
    translateService = TestBed.get(TranslateService);
    expect(translateService).toBeTruthy();
    checkTranslations(fixture, 'fr', translateService);
  }));
```

**translateHelper.ts**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export function checkTranslations(fixture: ComponentFixture<any>, language: string, translateService: any) {
  // Get all the content to be translated
  let contentToBeTranslated = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('*[translation]'));
  let beforeTranslationContent: string[] = [];

  contentToBeTranslated.forEach(debugElement => {
    beforeTranslationContent.push(debugElement.nativeElement.textContent);
  });

  // Test all english translations
  translateService.use(language).subscribe(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // Find missing translations
    contentToBeTranslated.forEach(debugElement => {
      expect(beforeTranslationContent.find(content => content == debugElement.nativeElement.textContent) ? true : false).toBe(false, ': Missing translation !');
    });
  });
}
```

So far so good, but if I add languages later on, I will have to add more unit tests for each language, and if I want to test my translations, I have to copy/paste all these tests for each language for each component.

---

My idea was to create a class that would get the current component `fixture` and `translateService` but how can I hook that up with the beforeEach() and everything ? Is it even possible at the moment ?

Any insight would be really helpful.

Comment: But what's the purpose of testing ngx-translate? It is already covered with tests, as any solid library. I would suggest to test the place where the translations are defined. This would be a real unit test.

Comment: Test for any missing translation in my code. It was just a beginning because I'm kinda new with angular tests

Comment: A good unit test involves only the part that is being tested. Other parts (translation service in this case) should preferably be stubbed/mocked. The way how this should be done depends on how ngx-translate is being used. This is not specific to Angular but to unit testing in general.

Comment: I agree, but then how do you test for regressions if somebody deletes a translation from a file ? This code allows me to check for any file if there are missing keys from my translate files which is pretty neat

Comment: Mocked service checks translated string against a file and throws an error if it is missing. Doing this with real service involves more moving parts and makes a test less concrete and more fragile. Technically, this is an integration test, not unit.

Comment: That is very true. I'll change that right away. Thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. This will probably work the way you've done that, but having isolated unit tests usually allows to detect the real problem quickly and unambiguously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its fully possible. We do it in our tests and its a good practice to have helpers to ensure DRY-ness and readability of your test code.

beforeEach() takes in a function so the only thing you need to do is create one for example.

```
export module TestHelpers {
  export function createComponent<T>(component: Type<T>,
                                     moduleDef: TestModuleMetadata = {},
                                     afterCreationFn: ((helper: Helpers<T>) => void) = noop) {
    return async(() => {
      const fixture = TestBed
        .configureTestingModule(moduleDef)
        .createComponent(component);
      afterCreationFn(new Helpers(fixture));
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });
  }

export class Helpers<T> {
    fixture: ComponentFixture<T>;

    constructor(fixture: ComponentFixture<T>) {
      this.fixture = fixture;
    }

    component() {
      return this.fixture.componentInstance;
    }
}
```

}

and in your test

```
beforeEach(TestHelpers.createComponent(
    TestComponent,
    {
      imports: [],
      declarations: [
        TestComponent
      ]
    },
    (h: Helpers<TestComponent>) => {
      helper = h;
      componentInstance = helper.component();
  }));
```

You can then implement the Helper class with any helper function to help you with your tests, all in one place

Comment: Cool ! I have two questions though : What is your `= noop` ? And how do you manage service injection from the root injector ? I get my service from the TestBed and with this setup I should get it from the component injectors ?

Comment: noop is just a no-op function `()=>{}`. Yes it would be a more correct way to do it `fixture.debugElement.injector.get(YourService);`

Comment: After trying, I'm kinda stuck with a few things... Could you provide an `Helper` example ? Since the `fixture` is in the Helper, does that mean all your tests are in this Helper ?

Comment: Yes but you can helper.fixture to get access to the fixture. Fixture is there so you can write helper functions using it instead of calling fixture directly